# Completely Remove OneDrive from Office Apps

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, onedrive

I would like to completely remove OneDrive integration from Office apps. This is the default menu:

[image]

I'd like to remove the highlighted section completely. I modified `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Internet` and created a `DWORD` with the tag `OnlineStorage` and set its value to `0x00000003`. This worked, and it removed onedrive. However, it also broke the smaller popup before the save as menu:
[image]

The popup doesn't show up anymore after disabling OneDrive via registry, it skips straight to the menu. Is there a way I can remove OneDrive but keep the popup?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is it possible you also disabled "[Backstage](https://www.urtech.ca/2017/03/solved-script-and-gpo-to-disable-backstage-when-saving-in-office-2016/)"? (this is the feature shown in your first screenshot)

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\General]
“SkipOpenAndSaveAsPlace”=dword:00000001

Comment: @Furty I checked, and that key didn't exist. Keeping my registry edit to disable OneDrive and inserting your edit didn't do much. Setting ```SkipOpenAndSaveAsPlace``` to ```dword:0x00000000``` didn't change anything, it still skipped the popup, and setting it to ```dword:0x00000001``` skipped all the way to Windows File Explorer. Thanks for trying, though.

Comment: In my opinion, your needs could not be met, the behavior is expected.The popup is mainly used to choose save files to OneDrive, SharePoint site and etc, although you could select the default location. It is one of the new features that Office connect to some cloud services through account. When no OneDrive or other cloud-based service are used to save files, the popup would not show up, there would be [a classical window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD6ET.jpg) as traditional Office.

Comment: @Emily Ah ok. Was hoping there was a way to keep that box. I'll wait some more time in case anyone shows up with a different opinion.

Comment: mmh, so what is better in your "Save this file" popup compared to the "broken"?